# Issue in Textfield default value set using the useEffect hook in the material-ui in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-effect

> I am trying to set the default value of Textfield in the react material-ui.
> It is working without the material-ui Textfield. But when I am using the Textfield it is not working. Ex. Working with "input" but not with "TextField".
> I want to use it for form editing purpose. Please help me to find out the solution. Thank you in advance.
> Below is the code for the example.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";



const submit = values => {
  console.log(values);
};
const initialValues = {
  name: '',
};
const Editform = () => {
  const [uname, setname] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
      setname("Jubed Alam"); //it should be default value. But not reflecting
  });
  return (
        <form>
            <TextField
                margin="normal"
                label="Name"
                fullWidth
                name="name"
                defaultValue={uname}
            />
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
  );
}

 export default Editform;
```

Answer (score 2):

i ran into same issue it fixed for me when I used multiline

```
<TextField
  required
  id="receiverName"
  label="Receiver Name"
  defaultValue={addressArray[0]}
  fullWidth
  multiline
  onChange={(e) => setRcvName(e.target.value)}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to update its default value in useEffect(). and use value instead of defaultValue, just do it like this:

```
    const Editform = () => {
      const [uname, setname] = useState("Jubed Alam");
     return (
        <form>
            <TextField
                margin="normal"
                label="Name"
                fullWidth
                name="name"
                value={uname}
                onChange={(e)=> setname(e.target.value)}
            />
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you are using value={uname} then I am not able to edit on the input field. That's why I was using the defaultvalue. Please check and help me finding the correct solution. Thank you

Comment: you have to use value and then set your state by onChange handler like : onChange={(e)=> setYourState(e.target.value)}

Comment: it's the correct way. we use defaultValue for Select Dropdown only to show the default value of the dropdown

Comment: I've copied your code and run it, it's working perfectly...